# Closing AlertDialog with Enter affects other activity

Tags: java, android

I have an Android device with physical keyboard attached.
One activity opens an AlertDialog that queries a string from the user.
I create the dialog like this

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setView(myView)
  .setPositiveButton("Ok", clickListener)
  .show();
```

myView contains a textbox and information text what to do. The ok button comes from the dialog.
clickListener reads the textbox on ok-click and enters text where it belongs.

Hitting enter first jumps from the textbox to the OK button, the second enter activates ok and closes the AlertDialog. (I will refine this to only need one enter but that's another story)

Then the underlying activity that executed this dialog selects a button in the activity, the button gets a "focused" look. It seems to react to enter too although I would assume the enter should be fully consumed in the AlertDialog.

What's going wrong here and can I avoid that somehow?

Comment: Is your question about why a view in the activity gets focus?

Comment: Yes, why in this special case. It's ok if some view gets focus if I press enter or also the cursor keys. But the enter key that closes the AlertDialog affects the activity too, that makes me wonder.